# How can I access the history of a file which was deleted then restored in git?

Tags: git

I restored a deleted file using: `git checkout some_commit deleted_file`, then I try to `git blame` it, but all its hisotry is lost. How can I keep the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git blame --reverse some_commit..HEAD  -- deleted_file
```